# CDC close contact definition - why masks addressed only in K12 setting?

Tags: covid-19, infection, coronavirus, risks, guidelines

CDC [defines](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/php/contact-tracing/contact-tracing-plan/appendix.html) close contact as

> Someone who was within 6 feet of an infected person
> (laboratory-confirmed or a clinically compatible illness) for a
> cumulative total of 15 minutes or more over a 24-hour period

I was interested why nothing was mentioned about masks: what if both persons wear masks.

Interestingly that fact is mentioned there but they specifically mention classroom setting:

> Exception: In the K–12 indoor classroom setting, the close contact
> definition excludes students who were within 3 to 6 feet of an
> infected student (laboratory-confirmed or a clinically compatible
> illness) where: both students were engaged in consistent and correct
> use of well-fitting masks;

Why using masks **in K-12 classroom setting and not somewhere else** excludes people within 3 to 6 feet from close contact definition? **Why only in K-12 classroom setting?**

Comment: The virus is changing all the time. The 6 feet and 15 minutes are now likely out of date with the Delta variant's spread. You'll also note that the quote above is not about "using masks", it's about "consistent and correct use of well-fitting masks", something which normally doesn't happen even when people are wearing masks out and about. In a classroom setting, the teacher can supervise mask use.

Comment: If it were something like "K-6", I'd expect it to be because small children aren't very effective at spreading the virus, but that's not the case for the full K-12 range.